# OpenComponents for rendering a whole page

Tags: anti-patterns, open-components

Since OpenComponents are intended for rendering small reusable components (with a well defined interface) inside a web page, would using an OpenComponent to render the whole page content including nested OpenComponents be a reasonable use case or would it be considered an anti-pattern?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen indeed OC used for whole pages and I have done it myself in the past.

One thing to reason about, in my opinion, is where the boundaries are in regards of modularising different parts as libraries (so, composition during build time) vs OCs (composition during render time).

In my opinion, despite that is a decision that can be easily reversed during the development, it is worth spending some time at the beginning, perhaps with some Proof of concepts, in order to understand how the development experience is in regard of developing, testing, and deploying.

In my experience, when the ownership of the entire OC content is on a specific team, it's ok to have everything inside modularised as libraries, as there is enough autonomy. When instead, multiple parts are owned by different stakeholders, it makes sense to reason about modularising via OCs, because OC makes easy to explicitly establish the contracts between interfaces and gives autonomy to different owners to develop and deploy independently.

In conclusion, I wouldn't say it is an anti-pattern.